# Another nonogram with story

Tags: grid-deduction, nonogram

Another nonogram with story but this time it's ZEBRA type. Clues in darker color describe what should be marked as FILLED. Clues in lighter color describe what should be marked as BLANK.

> After my Husband died, I couldn't even look at another Man for almost 20 years. But now that I'm [Solve to get the rest]

[image]

```
        ■ x ■ x ■ x ■ x ■ x
      |   3   3 3 1   1 2  
      | 1 3 3 2 1 2 7 3 4 3
  ----+--------------------
■   5 | o u t   o O p k T g
x 5 1 | f   p r i C w f B s
■   2 | o n ,   I   q P c a
x 1 3 | n , x : A o s   h o
■   9 | n t V B R r K n ? A
x   1 | e q y t s R K G w x
■ 1 5 | s l t l y v X D J t
x 4 2 | f   s a y     i N W
■ 1 1 | t   w h a s   w o h
x 3 4 | r t h v c   i t . P
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full message is

> After my Husband died, I couldn't even look at another Man for almost 20 years. But now that I'm **out of prison, I can honestly say it was worth it.**

Which can be seen by reading off the white tiles after solving the nonogram:

> [image]

Comment: Beat me to it by 30 seconds!  :P

Comment: dang, and you both beat me to it by a minute! good work.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain was fully expecting to be sniped myself :P

Comment: Regarding the story part - the wife killed her husband and was sent to women's prison for 20 years? We know it's a woman because she couldn't see another **man** for 20 years, which indicates a prison for women. And she says killing her husband was worth it? It's hard to pinpoint the reason, maybe he was abusive.